# Tutorials on Developing Custom Back ends for Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql, rest

Pretty new to Android development, so please forgive me if I say something stupid.  I am creating an Android app that I want to interface with a database that is already being used with a website (PHP + MySQL).  I know of Google App Engine, which looks great except it costs money after a certain amount of data transferred, and Parse, which I don't think is what I am looking for (and it costs $$$).

I've been searching for tutorials to make a custom back end using REST, but all the searches I get have something to do with Google App Engine.  Do any of you know of some tutorials to accomplish interfacing with a PHP/MySQL backend using REST for Android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) a helpful tutorial which shows you how to set up a very simple web service to be used with an Android application. I found it really easy to follow when I had to work on a similar project last year.

Basically, you need a web service as the back end. You can write one in Php. It should echo data encoded in JSON. After you're done with the web service, you'll need to make requests to it from your application and then decode and parse the returned JSON.

Also, try and Google "android rest web service tutorial". Good luck!

Comment: Link to answers are discouraged and should include a portion from that page, should the link cease to exist.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. I'm new here. I'll edit this.

Comment: This looks like a great start.  Thanks Dodu!